# Notepad++ HTML custom tag does not highlight attribute strings

Tags: html, tags, notepad++

Notepad++ doesn't appear to highlight attribute strings in HTML elements with custom tag names.

For instance:

```
<div id="wrapper"/>
```

Applies the correct style color to "wrapper" from the "doublestring" entry in the style configurator. However, writing:

```
<custom-tag id="wrapper"/>
```

Does not color "wrapper". In fact, the entire contents of the element are of the tag color.

I'm assuming that Notepad++ picks from a certain list of predefined tags and only considers those correct syntax, but I've searched far and wide and I failed to find a solution.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've found the solution.

The style configurator appears to be bugged and doesn't allow you to add custom keywords to most of the fields, but you can add them yourself through the langs.xml file.

Navigate to your Notepad++ directory if you don't use appdata or to %APPDATA%/Notepad++ if you do and find the langs.xml file. Make sure you're not modifying langs.model.xml instead as that seems to be a template file (that is the mistake I was making).

Search for

```
<Language name="html"
```

And add your keyword inside the massive list of keywords that follows it.

Restart Notepad++ and that should be it.

Comment: You can make an infinite number of custom tags. It's not a solution. The solution is to report it as a bug